# Is there a way I can pass the properties from ant build script to Jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins

I have a ant build which calculates the next build number with some script and builds and deploys the project. I want to tag the source after a successful build with the module version just built. Since the module version is automatic I need a mechanism to pass that dynamic value back to Jenkins so it can use it as the tag name.

Any help and advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable generated by Jenkins? Would be a lot simpler See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Comment: I want to do manual releases at times, so i cant have that one.

Comment: Not meaning to be difficult but wouldn't that mean the tagging should also happen within the ANT build?

Comment: Honestly, thats a very good idea :) thank you. I think i should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is useful for tagging but it’s possible to do this using the EnvIvject Jenkins plugin ant the ant <propertyfile> task.  Use <propertyfile> to output any ant properties you wish to export to Jenkins to a file. Then use the EnvInject plugin to create a build step to bring the values in the file into Jenkins as variables.